# Design Border Bottom

Tags: html, css

I would like to design a border like below picture. But I am running out of ideas about how to do it.
[image]

https://codepen.io/szn0007/pen/VRGPyE

```
div.about-me h2{
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

THank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily with CSS you have access to two [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) on every container. I added the Asterix to one of the pseudo elements `:after` and the line to another `:before`.

For example:

```css
.fancy-underline {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.fancy-underline:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 10px);
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: grey;
}

.fancy-underline:after {
  content: '*';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="fancy-underline">About Me</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this out:

```
           <div class="about-me">
           <h2>About Me</h2>
           <p>*</p>
           </div>
```

css:

```
          div.about-me{
           width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
          }

          div.about-me h2{
          color: #000;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
          width: 20%;
          margin: 0 auto;
          padding: 20px;
          }

         p {
         font-size: 50px;

         transform: translatey(-72px);

         }
```